# Is there any Vim formatter plugin that support customized style?

Tags: software-recommendation, vim-plugin

Is there any autoformatter plugin for vim that support customized style? Like, adding space after parentheses, place curly brackets in current line and something like that?

What I want to achieve is a customized auto format, so I can format my code like this:

```
void function () {
    cout << "This format" << endl;
}
```

Instead of like this:

```
void function ()
{
    cout << "Not this format" << endl;
}
```

I've installed `vim-autoformat`. It's automated format is like the second style. So, is there any vim autoformatter that can be customized?

Comment: Better a) detail the question a bit more (I suppose you are speaking of C code formatting? or what? Can you give an example? What have you tried?) and b) better ask it on http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Updated. And sorry, I didn't know vim has it's own stackexchange.

Comment: @BagolDaplun [vi.se] is relatively new, but questions still remain on-topic here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`vim-autoformat`](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat) plugin uses `astyle` to perform the indentation, and `astyle` supports a variety of indentation styles. The one you are looking for maybe close to the K&R or Java styles. Match your preferred style to one in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style), and to the corresponding options for [`astyle`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/astyle.1). Then add to your `.vimrc`, for example using the [One True Brace Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_1TBS):

```
let g:formatprg_c = "astyle"
let g:formatprg_args_c = " --style=1tbs "
```

Comment: I see. Is there any list of available format there? The site doesn't seems provide a complete list.

Comment: @BagolDaplun I don't know, but I think all the styles mentioned in the `astyle` manpage are covered by the Wiki article, so a more complete list wouldn't be of much use anyway.